# selectize do not render options dynamically

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I am trying to use selectize for search and select option in Dropdown. User is searching for student name and then drop down must show suggestion as user types.

```
$('#studentSearchBox').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name'],
    maxOptions: 10,
    options: [],
    create: false,
    render: {
            option: function(item, escape) {
                console.log(item)
                    return '<div>' +escape(item.name)+'</div>';
            }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
            if (!query.length) return callback();
            $.ajax({
                    url: "\list", //url is correct as I can get json response
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                            q: query
                    },
                    error: function() {
                            callback();
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                            callback(res.data);
                    }
            });
    },
    onChange: function(){
        window.location = this.items[0];
    }
});
```

json data return  - {'1':'Jon','2':'Jhonsan','3':'Jerry','4':'Jules'}

But the returned json data is not rendering in browser.No console error !

html

```
<select class="form-control selectized" id="mySearchBox" name="sid" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><option value="" selected="selected"></option></select>
<div class="selectize-control form-control single">
<div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 4px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown single form-control" style="display: none; width: 555px; top: 42px; left: 8px; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
            <div data-value="1" data-selectable="" class="option">Jon</div> 
            <div data-value="2" data-selectable="" class="option">Jasmine</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried another way $('#studentSearchBox').selectize(); but the loading of options are very slow..any idea why?

Comment: did you get it work? I am facing the same issue and no idea what is going on.

Comment: I had another js for in-place editing hence it was removing classes applied by selectize js. May be you need to check if the required classes are applied to make it work. And, remember to handle it as div not as dropdown. This might help.

Comment: Man, you're my hero. It was <select> instead of the <div>. Make it an answer, so I can vote up.

Comment: Glad it helped :). I spent almost a day to figure things out ...

Answer (score 1):

I had another js for in-place editing hence it was removing classes applied by selectize js. May be you need to check if the required classes are applied to make it work. And, remember to handle it as div not as dropdown. This might help

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean to "handle it as div not as dropdown"? I'm having an issue with my custom render function not being called, and trying to determine if your answer which worked for you and helped Grzegorz will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonBeck not sure of the problem, but treat it as div if you see the html it will give you more clarity how selectize  is manipulating the <select>